# How do I view the last request from Zend_Soap_Client->getLastRequest() after a soap fault exception?

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap

I am using a Zend_Soap_Client to call a web service. I am getting an exception from the error which I suspect is down to me not sending something along with the request:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Sender] SOAP-ERROR:
>   Encoding: object hasn't 'V24Flag' propert

Because it throws an exception I want to try view what is the actual request being sent, however because of the exception, I can not use Zend_Soap_Client->getLastRequest() to get the request (it returns null). Looking at the Zend_Soap_Client->getLastRequest() its a thin wrapper for soapClient->__soapCall() which I'm not sure how to dig deeper from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is actually slightly different to what you think it is.  The reason `Zend_Soap_Client::getLastRequest()` returns `NULL` for you is that no request was ever made: the error is being thrown at the stage where the request internally is being compared against the WSDL you are using.  So the method is perfectly correct to return `NULL`.

As to how to form the parameter for your SOAP call so this error isn't thrown, I can't be of much greater help right now (I expect it depends partly on the services you are integrating with), but there's a userland answer on [the php.net page for `SoapClient::__soapCall()`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php#92645) which may point you in a fruitful direction.  Essentially, some people seem to have got somewhere by doing a deep conversion of an array structure into `stdClass` objects.  That doesn't seem to be the whole story (it isn't for the issue I'm currently investigating), and indeed this may be down to [a bug in PHP](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53234), but I hope it helps you towards an answer.

Comment: Spot on! By getting $client->__getTypes() I can pinpoint which parameter and datatype was causing the issue

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
    try {
        $client = new Zend_Soap_CLient();
        $client->doSomething($params);

    } catch(SoapFault $f) {
        echo $f->getTraceAsString();
    }
```

Btw. Zend_Soap_Client->getLastRequest() wraps SoapClient::__getLastRequest();

Comment: Unfortunately the SoapFault won't contain information about the request itself.  `__getLastRequest()` should return the request body if the `trace` option in set to be on in the `SoapClient` - that's if a request was ever attempted.